# How to delete all virtual registry keys of an application?

Tags: windows, windows-7, registry

I have an application that makes use of registry. The application worked fine on Win XP however when I run it on Win 7 it crashes.
The reason is registry virtualization. Apparently my application is reading the old values written to virtual registry that were not removed when I uninstalled the old version.
How can I make sure all virtual registry keys are removed when I uninstall a program? (assuming I'm not using tools like install shield, etc...)

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor, you'll see the keys it reads from the trace it provides.  Renaming the top-level key is an obvious way to get ahead btw.  Including the major version number of your app in the key name is highly advisable.  As is making sure that your uninstaller removes junk, probably too late for that.

Comment: @HansPassant `As is making sure that your uninstaller removes junk` Exactly, but the `how` is my question. Is there a way find virtualized registry keys for my application and remove them when uninstall it?

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  The only thing you could do wrong is not trying it.